# Error while removing from deque

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I have an `std::deque<CustomType>`, I am trying to remove a member whose location I do not know. Therefore, I am first finding it and then removing it.

```
/* 
  Remove from - members, which is the private variable of std::deque<User> type
*/
void Group::remove_member(User u) {  
    if(this->is_member(u)) {
           std::deque<User>::iterator iter;
           iter = std::find(this->members.begin(), this->members.end(), u);
           if(iter != this->members.end()) {
                this->members.erase(iter);
           }
     }
}
```

However, the compiler (GCC) is throwing an error which seems like missing Operator Overloading.

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/algorithm:62,
from Group.cpp:4:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h: In function ‘_RandomAccessIterator std::__find(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_Deque_iterator<User, User&, User*>, _Tp = User]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:4224:   instantiated from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = std::_Deque_iterator<User, User&, User*>, _Tp = User]’
Group.cpp:36:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:174: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:178: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:182: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:186: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:194: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:198: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:202: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.std::_Deque_iterator<_Tp, _Ref, _Ptr>::operator* [with _Tp = User, _Ref = User&, _Ptr = User*]() == __val’
```

Comment: I think `std::deque` allows deletion from the front or back only. Which is what deque is about.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `User`?

Comment: I have a feeling you have not declared `bool User::operator==(const User&)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444833/error-while-removing-from-deque#comment16733641_12444833).

> I have a feeling you have not declared `bool User::operator==(const User&)`

The error is telling you that its attempting to do `*iterator == ...` inside the implementation of `std::find`. The problem, however, is that you have not overloaded `operator==` for `User`. Try declaring a member function inside `User` as follows...

```
bool operator==(const User&);
```

Now, define it to provide some meaningful semantic equality between `User`s, otherwise `std::find` doesn't know how to compare them.

---

As a side note, why doesn't `Group::remove_member` take `const User&` rather than `User`?

Comment: After reading your comment, I already started doing what you suggested. Let me see if it works. BTW, how will `const User&` make things better? (I'm relatively new to C++)

Comment: Passing by `const` reference avoids copying the object while simultaneously preventing the object from being used as a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: Thanks! The error is resolved and also for the valuable advice. :)

Answer (score 1):

Like @oldrinb mentioned, you need to tell explicitly how to test the equality of two `User` class. Otherwise the `find` algorithm won't be able to locate the item you look for. This is done by overriding the `==` operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class MyCustomClass{
  public:
    MyCustomClass(int id) : id_(id) { }

   // Would produce the same error without this
   bool operator==(const MyCustomClass& b){
     return id_ == b.id_;
   }

   int id(){ return id_; }

  private:
    int id_;
};

int main(void){
  deque<MyCustomClass> q;
  q.push_back(MyCustomClass(1));
  q.push_back(MyCustomClass(2));
  q.push_back(MyCustomClass(3));
  deque<MyCustomClass>::iterator it = 
    find(q.begin(), q.end(), MyCustomClass(2));

  if ( it != q.end() ){
    printf("Found\n");
    q.erase(it);
  }else{
    printf("Not Found!\n");
  }

  for(it = q.begin(); it != q.end() ; it++)
    printf("%d ", it->id());

  printf("\n");

  return 0;
}
```